# Unreachable Code, when applying foreach on entities in EF context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, foreach

```
DB.DBEntities ent = new DB.DBEntities();

foreach (var brn in ent.Sites.ToList()) 
{
     //Do work                 
}
```

If I try above code, it gives Unreachable code on var branch

But if I store the list in another list object and iterate on it, no warning is given.(As below)

```
DB.DBEntities ent = new DB.DBEntities();
List<DB.Site> list = ent.Sites.ToList();

foreach (var brn in list) 
{
     //Do work                 
}
```

Can some one please explain why does this happen?

Comment: Is there some code between the initialization of `ent` and the `foreach` loop ?

Comment: What's inside the `foreach`? Any `break` statements or anything, like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476438/c-sharp-unreachable-code-detected. Also, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067886/why-is-the-code-in-my-foreach-unreachable-exact-copy-of-working-code-thats-bee

Comment: No, absolutely nothing in between. No break statements either